# How to change Sharepoint database size?

Tags: sharepoint-server, database, database-server

Currently I'm facing an issue of insufficient size of my SharePoint database, and I need to edit the:

1. Autogrowth of the db
2. Maximum size file limit

Where do I go to change these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to go the SQL Server where you Database is located. 
Open the SQL Server Management Studio.
Go to you required DB and right click to get "Properties".

[image]

Click on ellipses as shown in red.

you will get a window as below.
[image]

You can change as per your requirement.

Be sure when you change.

Answer (score 2):

Two things,

1. First, you have to make sure that you have enough disk space on Data Drive and Log Drive on the SQL server.
2. Secondly, you have to make sure that you did not cap the maximum Size for the Database. If thats the case then you can also use the SQL script.

**For the Max Size check this**

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [myDatabaseName] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'myDatafileNAme', SIZE = 10240KB )
GO
```

For AutoGrowth Please check this:

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyTechMantra]
    MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'MyTechMantra', FILEGROWTH = 512MB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyTechMantra]
    MODIFY FILE
        (NAME = N'MyTechMantra_log', FILEGROWTH = 256MB )
GO
```

[How to Change SQL Server Database Auto Growth Settings](https://mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/How-to-Change-SQL-Server-Database-Auto-Growth-Settings.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please open Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and find the database which you used .

Right click this DB and select properties , select files , modify the value ”initial size” to expected size and click ok.

[image]

After process finish , please restart SQL server service :

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager , restart SQL server service :

[image]